# Database query returning only the first element of the data base as the same instance for all, in ASP.NET MVC Core 6

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core-6.0

I am having some trouble and cannot figure out why my sql database is returning the first data entry as all the other entries.This is my method to get all the database table entries from the table called HealthDataFuture

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AjaxMethod(string id)
        {
            List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
            chartData.Add(new object[]
                            {
                            "Months", "SOFAS"
                            });
            //FOR SOME REASON IT KEEPS READING THE FIRST DATABASE ENTRY ONLY SO THERE ALL THE ENTRIES ARE THE SAME VALUE
            
            foreach (HealthDataFuture data in _db.HealthDataFuture)
            {
                if (data.id == id)
                {
                    chartData.Add(new object[]
                        {
                            data.Month, data.Sofas
                        });
                }
            }

            return Json(chartData);
        }
```

[image: This is my model]

This is my database table entries, it's returning the first entry as all the other ones when I query all of it, they have the same id because i want to return all of them and then graph

[image: This is my database table entries, its returning the first entry as all the other ones too]

This is the results i keep getting back

[image: This is the results i keep getting back]

i have also tried this way of getting data however it is the same problem

-------EDIT ----- PROBLEM RESOLVED
It turns out my MYSQL table model was not created properly as there was no primary key nor foreign key

Comment: What is the type of `_db` and how do you fill it?

Comment: The db works with other tables i use and it is public DataVizController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;

        }        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Mind https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: i will try my best

Comment: I have some issues in your code that I cannot understand. The first one: in EF, the entities are plural nouns. But in your pictures `_db.HealthDataFuture` is not. It's not important. Next: I know that, `foreach` doesn't let to change the collection while iteration. How do you remove items? And the last one.: You don't call `SaveChanges` in your code. So any other instance of `ApplicationDbContext` cannot see your changes.

Comment: Couldn't you just filter as part of the data retrieval, e.g. `var dataList = _db.HealthDataFuture.Where(x => x.Id = TempData["Id"]).ToList()`. Also worth noting that you are passing the `id` back to the model, so never actually do anything with the list. Finally, attributes go before the property, so you've limited your sofa property to 1-12, not the month property.

Comment: Also, from your screenshot of SSMS it looks like both `Id` and `Month` are integers. Why are they strings in your model?

Comment: i think it might be something wrong with my table, i replicated it in a new project and the table HealthDataFuture only returns the first element as the value for all other entries, however on my other table i can retrieve all the data values and it doesnt repeat the first one

Comment: I was just testing to see if it retrieved all the correct values with all these delete stuff

Comment: Should i create post my minimal reproduction on a github so that anyone can clone to see if they have the same problem?

Comment: Can you show your DbContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better not to share image, but code using correct tag. To use code helps other users and all the cummunity, for example it makes your question searchable.

Anyway you can try to do in this way:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)){
    List<HealthDataFuture> DataList = _db.HealthDataFuture.Where(x => h.Id == id).ToList();
    return View(id);
}
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

I've also some question about your code:

1. What should it do?
2. DataList is like a select query from db, but nobody is using DataList. Why?

The more details you provide, the more information we have to help you.

Editing after comments:

If you want to remove data from db you should use saveChanges. For example, if you want to remove all lines with id other than "1", you can try:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)){
    _db.HealthDataFuture.RemoveRange(_db.HealthDataFuture.Where(x => h.Id != id));
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return View(id);
}
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

You can also read something about access to DB in async way, it's recommended and it perfoms better: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/ef/core/miscellaneous/async

Comment: i just wanted to use debug to see what is in the datalist when i grabbed it, Thanks for all the tips i am new to this. The problem has to do with my database tables, i am currently dropping  the database and re migrating and updating it

Comment: I'll add more details in response

Comment: Yes, it seems like the problem was with the database table, still thanks for all the help !!!! My database table for this model did not have primary key, so i added that and and a foreign key to link it to my other table